# if adding the text field on uitableview then textfield does not call its delegate methods

Tags: objective-c

If I am using this code then the `UITextField` does not call its `delegate` method. In  this code I am adding the `UITextField` on the `UITableView`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {          
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            if (indexPath.row!=7) 
            {

            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

            //Creating Lable

            UILabel *lblText= [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53, 30, 150, 35)];


            [lblText setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
            lblText.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

            lblText.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];


            lblText.text = [labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



            //creating a the textField 

            UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
            [txtField setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 56, 220, 31)];

            [txtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


            [txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            txtField.delegate=self;
            [txtField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
            txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
                txtField.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                txtField.enabled=YES;                


            if (indexPath.row==2)
            {
                txtField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            }
            else if(indexPath.row==3)
            {
                txtField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

            }else
                {

                    txtField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

                }

                if (indexPath.row==6 ||indexPath.row==5) 
                {
                    [txtField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
                }

            txtField.tag=indexPath.row;
            [cell addSubview:txtField];

            [cell addSubview:lblText];  
        } 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: have you declared <UITextFieldDelegate> in your .h file

Comment: ya i m declare the <UITextFieldDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. Since I couldn't find the answer on stackoverflow anywhere, here's what worked for me:

In addition to 
1) making the outlet for the field from the storyboard to the UITableViewController code, and 
2) declaring the  in the UITableViewController code,

I had to

3) hook up the delegate outlet via the storyboard as well: 
a) Go to the storyboard and click on the UITextField in question,
b) Go to the Connections Inspector panel for that UITextField and ctl+drag the delegate plus sign to the UITableViewController that the UITextField exists on in the storyboard. (I dragged across to the UITableViewController in the storyboard outline on the far left)

After that, my UITableViewController fired all the UITextFieldDelegate methods just fine.